# Spring Boot 2 HandlerInterceptor not called before auth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, security, spring-security

Say I have a common maven package which configures:

- authentication via a class that extends `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and an `AuthenticationProvider`
- a few things (cors...) with a class that implements `WebMvcConfigurer`

Now, in my app, which uses the common maven package as a dependency, I register a handler interceptor as follows:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyWebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  private final MyService myService;

  @Override
  public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor(cookieService));
  }

}
```

When authentication via an authentication provider fails, a 401 response is returned, but my interceptor is never called.

I suspect:

- the authentication provider is earlier in the filter chain and the request doesn't make it to the interceptor
- <s>the `WebMvcConfigurer` in the common dependency is registered before that in my app, and the interceptor registry instance passed to both configurers is not the same, and my app only uses the interceptor registry from the dependency.</s> I can confirm they receive the same registry instance.

Spring Gurus I'm listening :)

Comment: Security is implemented through filters, which execute before a servlet (the `DispatcherServlet` is responsible for executing the interceptors). On a different note don't add `@EnableWebMvc` unless you want to disable the Spring Boot default Web MVC configuration!.

Comment: @M.Deinum good point. You've actually helped me fix a bug with the `@EnableWebMvc` notice. Regarding my initial question, do you have an idea how I can register a filter without having access to the security configurer ?

Comment: Just add a filter as an `@Bean` and an `FilterRegistrationBean` for additional information like urls, methods etc.

Comment: I am able to do so, but stil can't get it to execute because it seems to register after Spring Security filters. I have tried setting the order to `Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE`. Event changed `spring.security.filter.order` to 5 and set `@Order(4)` but still not getting executed :/

Comment: Nevermind, it was executed. I was testing with MockMvc which does not register filters by default. I had to write another test using RestTemplate and calling localhost  using `@LocalServerPort`. Thanks a lot !